# Mootools WMD editor doesn't properly quote content

Tags: mootools, wmd

I'm using the mootools WMD editor but it seems like there's an error in the script and it doesn't properly format selected content after I hit the quote button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command` was not defined. I saw no references in the script to `command` and I looked at a nearby function that did the formatting.

I simply changed line 1916:

```
            command.wrap(chunk, mooWMD.Config.lineLength - 2);
```

to

```
            chunk.wrap( mooWMD.Config.lineLength -2 );
```

Which seems to do the trick.